# data table in iOS

Tags: ios, xml, sqlite, uitableview

I want to ask something about iOS .I get the values from xml file after that I parsed and I want to insert database (sqlite).How can I do this.How can I create dynamic tables and columns .Do you have such a structure in objective c .
 similar datatable c#.

Answer (score 1):

The [Sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) C API is accessible directly (you need to link the build product against libsqlite3 in the link with libraries build phase). You can either write elements to a pre-created sqlite database (if you already know the structure of the data), or store the elements in NSMutableArray/NSMutableDictionary until the XML parsing has ended (provided the XML data isn't too huge to fit sensibly into memory). Then create an appropriate database to store the data.

You can also use core data which is the apple recommended way (and which uses sqlite under the hood), with a nicer object oriented API.

The C API is described in detail [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html), and it links to specific examples for many different common sqlite operations. There are also objective C wrappers for sqlite like [this one](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) if you're uncomfortable with C.

Comment: Thanks .Im new in objective c.But How can I generate table and its columns dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Define an object class with all the relevant fields you find in the XML (title, date, description etc), then iterate through the parsed XML creating a new object for each row. Once the object has been populated, store it in a MutableArray and move onto the next.

You can then pass this structured array to your database, where you can again loop through it and extract the values. You might want to read up on FMDB as it has a lot of useful functions built in to aid this.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use SQLite with iOS. Better there is [Core Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started).